Sum of subspaces $V$ and $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(W)=n$
If $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(W)=n$ and $V\cap W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, can we immediately say that \begin{equation} V\oplus W=\mathbb{R}^n ?\end{equation}
Why or why not?

What have you tried? Something good to think about would be the explicit formula for $\dim(V+W)$ in terms of some of the things you already have...

You're referring to the theorem where dim(V)+dim(W)=dim(V+W)+dim(V$\cap$W)=dim(V$\oplus$W), right? If so, I'm not sure how this relates with the sum of the subspaces themselves?

Use the fact that if $B$ is a vector space, and $A$ is a subspace of the vector space, and $\dim(A)=\dim(B) $ , then $A=B$
